# Does redshift not work with local aws profile creds?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam

The way authing to aws APIs is suppose to work is you setup your profile locally in the .aws folder and the API is smart enough to look there for creds.

But Im setting up redshift odbc and I have to hard code this? Its not smart enough to look at my profile settings in `C:\Users\MEEE\.aws\credentials`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if you are able to get the credentials via the CLI?

```
aws redshift get-cluster-credentials --cluster-identifier <ClusterName>
 --db-user <UserName> --db-name <DBName> --duration-seconds 3600 --profile <ProfileName>
```

Did you follow the exact steps mentioned here? You also need to provide your cluster details as well.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-iam-credentials-configure-jdbc-odbc.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/options-for-providing-iam-credentials.html#using-configuration-profile

Comment: In the odbc GUI "AWS Profile" still asks for user and password. I should just have to provide the profile name